# Do men have more Chochma than women?

Tags: sources-mekorot, women, men-male, gender-identity

I've seen many blogs and other modern day books write that men have more Chochmah than women. Some examples:

> [A man’s forte is chochma, and a woman’s is binah.](https://www.hidabroot.com/article/171533/The-Status-of-a-Woman-in-Judaism---Rabbi-Zamir-Cohen)
>
> [Kabbalah teaches that men have more Chochma (wisdom) and women a greater measure of Bina (understanding).](https://www.meaningfullife.com/women-equal-to-men/)
>
> [Men are from Chochmah; Women are from Binah](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/109686/jewish/Men-are-from-Chochmah-Women-are-from-Binah.htm)
>
> [The first of the properties is that of chochmah, translated loosely as “wisdom,” which is a male principle.](http://www.chabad.org/theJewishWoman/article_cdo/aid/376141/jewish/The-Role-of-Women-in-Judaism.htm)
>
> [Men's brains with their superior Chochmah mode...](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/109687/jewish/The-ChochmahBinah-Dichotomy-II-Joe-We-Need-to-Talk.htm)
>
> [Women are more attuned to binah and malchut. Men are more inclined to chochma and tiferet.](https://www.naaleh.com/feminism-and-judaism-v6n46)

Is there a valid source for this? The closest thing I'm aware of is [Yomah 66b](https://www.sefaria.org/Yoma.66b.12?lang=he&with=Commentary&lang2=he)

> אין חכמה לאשה אלא בפלך וכן הוא אומר (שמות לה, כה) וכל אשה חכמת לב בידיה טוו

but I don't think that's a valid Mekor at all. [See the end of this article for example.](http://www.daat.ac.il/he-il/mishpacha/maamad/feminizem/%D7%97%D7%9B%D7%9E%D7%AA%D7%9F-%D7%91%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%AA%D7%9F-%D7%A9%D7%9C-%D7%A0%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%9D.htm?printview=true) Also see there for a number of sources that women are referred to as having significant amounts of Chochmah (although there's no implication there who has more- men or women).

Comment: In Kabbala, חכמה and בינה are called אבא ואימא respectively. I don't know where these names first appear, but maybe this is the source for the idea.

Comment: How are we defining Chochmah and Binah?

Comment: @DonielF I don't feel that that's relevant if we're just looking for a source... So long as any source acceptable to Eliyahu would say "Men have more chochma than women", no matter what the definition, it would answer the question.

Comment: What sort of source are you looking for? You yourself linked a half-dozen articles that quote this, are those considered 'sources'? I only looked at the first two articles (so far), and they both seem to have have sources behind them (for example, Niddah 45b in the first article and Sichos of the Rebbe for the second one). Are those sources valid?

Comment: The Gemara in Nidda only says that women have more Binah. I'm looking for an early source that men have more Chochma (preferably Rishonim or earlier but I'd accept a little later as well)

Comment: @רבותמחשבות Sure, but this question (to some, like the now-deleted answer) sounds like it’s asking if men are smarter than women. Clearly it’s not, but to avoid any issues it might be better to translate the terms in the OP.

Comment: חָכְמָה מוחָא אִיהִי מַחֲשָׁבָה מִלְּגָאו. בִּינָה לִבָּא וּבָהּ הַלֵּב מֵבִין.  https://he.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A4%D7%AA%D7%99%D7%97%D7%AA_%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%94%D7%95_%D7%94%D7%A0%D7%91%D7%99%D7%90. Patach Eliyahu from Tikunei Zohar daf 17

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Daf al Hadaf to Niddah 45b](http://files.daf-yomi.com/bookfiles/daf-al-hadaf-nida/daf-al-hadaf-nida210.pdf) says clearly that men have more Chochmah than women.  He bases this on the contradiction between Shabbos 33b (נשים דעתן קלות) and Niddah 45b (בינה יתירה באשה יותר מבאיש) and explains this to be the distinction between the two Gemaras.  He also quotes Yoma 66b as support, despite your issues with this.

He quotes 2 sources for his claim:

- the Sefer Chasam Sofer quoted earlier on that page in Daf al Hadaf (Seder Avodas Hayom, which I have been unable to find), which makes some comments which I will not explain here in English והמעיין יעיין.
- The Maharal in Chiddushei Agados here, who makes this distinction openly.  He discusses the difference between men and women as שכל הנבדל vs. שכל היולאני, and associates the שכל הנבדל with Chochma, and the שכל היולאני with Binah.

Comment: I also didn't find the Chassam Sofer but the Maharal in Chiddushei Aggados was perfect. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Eliyahu Np.  Happy to help, keep on asking good questions!

Comment: What do sechel Hanivdal and sechel Hyolani translate to?

Comment: @YaakovPinchas see https://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/intellect and see maharal there

Comment: So you're saying that men have more chochma and women more binah, however blurry these terms may be?

Comment: @bach I'm presenting these sources for interested parties - read them as you wish.

Comment: @רבותמחשבות sorry, I don’t see the Maharal mentioned there, do you know where in the article I could see your source?

Comment: @YaakovPinchas The Maharal is in the answer post (in Chiddushei Aggados). The relevant section from the article is:

Comment: Human intellect is analyzed as a faculty of the soul and regarded as one of the internal senses. It is that which receives the already semiabstracted perceptions, known as phantasms, from the soul's intellectually disposed imagination or memory, and brings the process of abstraction and generalization to completion.

Comment: The explanation of the process of disengagement from matter is facilitated for the later philosophers by their subdivision of the Aristotelian concept of active and passive states of intellect into a number of stages. Chief among these are the "hylic" (material), or "potential," intellect, viewed either as an incorporeal substance (following *Themistius) or as a disposition of the body to receive intelligibles (following *Alexander of Aphrodisias); the intellect "in act" and its counterpart, intellect "in habitu,"

Comment: which express an intellect that has become under the influence of the Agent Intellect actual and experienced; and the "acquired" intellect, representing intellectual perfection and conjunction with the world of eternal substances (a world also identified with the angelic realm; see F. Rahman's summary of the influential views of al-Fārābī and Avicenna, Prophecy in Islam (1958), 11–29; and see Levi ben Gershom's survey, Milḥamot ha-Shem, Part I).

Comment: @רבותמחשבות My mistake, I thought the Maharal was mentioned in the link. I appreciate the quoted text too, thank you.

Comment: @YaakovPinchas no problem, glad it was helpful

Answer (score 2):

HaRav Tzadok HaKohen of Lublin זצ"ל writes in [דובר צדק](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14371&st=&pgnum=43&hilite=) (last paragraph on page) that binah is a female trait that is rooted in the heart, whilst חכמה, wisdom, belongs to the male consciousness and stems from the brain. Quoting the זוהר he writes, "חכמה ובינה הם אבא ואימא" – “Wisdom and understanding – they are the father (i.e. wisdom) and the mother (i.e. understanding)”.